# sql condition on all

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a column with values either 'a', 'b' or 'c'. User input can be one of them or 'all'. How do I put a condition on 'all'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `or`:

```
where (:user_val = 'all' or :user_val = column)
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Gordon's answer...

If you have a the following table:

```
_______________________
| column 1 | column 2 | 
|---------------------|
|     a    |    1     |
|---------------------|
|     b    |    2     |
|---------------------|
|     c    |    3     |
|---------------------|
```

You can do:

```
Select *
from table t
where (@input = 'all' or t.column1 = @input)
```

If `@input = 'all'`, the first part of the `or` evaluates to true, returning all 3 rows. If `@input = 'a'`, only the first row `a 1` will return.