# Wordpress PHP Prepared SQL Query with Wildcard

Tags: sql, wordpress, wildcard

I am having an issue in wordpress performing a prepared SQL query. I have a database that records manufacturers of cars.

The user can choose which car manufacturer they want to search the database for and it will return results.

The user has the following options to select from, they can select only one option BMW, AUDI, OPEL, ALL.

If they choose all it should return results for all car manufacturers in the database.

The below code works fine is the user selects BMW, AUDI, OPEL but fails to return any results if the user selects ALL.

**PHP CODE**

```
//user has a dropdown where they can choose either BMW, AUDI, OPEL, ALL

$chosenCarManufacturer = "ALL";

$results =  $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "
          SELECT * FROM database_cars 
          WHERE carModel = %s",  
        $chosenCarManufacturer 
    ) 
);

print_r( $results );
```

Comment: When you run `SELECT * FROM database_cars WHERE carModel = 'ALL'` in your database, do you get any results?  Why not just remove the `where` clause if `ALL` is selected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql condition on all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430516/sql-condition-on-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Austin for the solution. I used the OR condition you suggested and passed the same string the the prepare method twice for the 2 place holders. Final working code below:

```
//user has a dropdown where they can choose either BMW, ``AUDI, OPEL, ALL

$chosenCarManufacturer = "ALL";

$results =  $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "
          SELECT * FROM database_cars 
          WHERE carModel = %s or 'All' = %s",  
        $chosenCarManufacturer,
        $chosenCarManufacturer 
    ) 
);

print_r( $results );
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that there is no `carModel` for "ALL".

As I recommended in my comment, just write logic that omits the `WHERE` clause if "ALL" is selected.

I've never written much PHP, but something like this should do it, no?

```
if($chosenCarManufacturer == 'ALL') {
    $results =  $wpdb->get_results(
       //just a literal query since there are no parameters 
       $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM database_cars");
    )
} else {
    $results =  $wpdb->get_results(
       //use a prepared statement with parameters/placeholders
       $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM database_cars WHERE carModel = %s",  
          $chosenCarManufacturer
       ) 
    );
}
```

There's probably a cleaner way, but I'm just trying to cobble together the idea for the approach based on what little syntax I kinda know.

Comment: Marc, Thanks for the response. Yes "ALL" is not a carModel, I simply want to return all car models in that database if the user selects all. I could write some logic that omits the WHERE clause but that would throw an error as the query  would then  not contain the correct number of placeholders (1) for the number of arguments passed (1). As $chosenCarManufacturer is still being passed.

Comment: Then change the logic in your code. If `carModel` is `ALL` then run a regular `get_results()` query *without* the `prepare()` call as you'll be fetching all cars. If `carModel` is **not** `ALL`, then run the code you have now.

Comment: @MikeMoynihan, I updated my answer to be more explicit.